# how to make update of form fields "data is from database" in react

Tags: reactjs

I try to build a site similar to wikipedia and its Edit functionality trouble me

think I send some data from DB like this

```
{
"post":[
{"title":"SOME TITLE","date":"20-12-2021"},
{"title":"SOME TITLE 2","date":"20-11-2021"}
]
}
```

with this data I need to show data to user and as well option to edit as well
so this means title and date are in some sort state variable I guess

how to achieve this I don't know I make question right but please consider wikipedia edit feature as example

how to implement it in react

Thanks

```
import { Form, Input, Button, Col, Row } from "antd";
import { PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const minusStyle = {
  position: "relative",
  margin: "0 8px",
  color: "#999",
  fontSize: "24px",
  cursor: "pointer",
  transition: "all 0.3s",
};

const PanditComponent = ({
  panditNamez,
  panditContactz,
  onChangeSetPanditName,
  onChangeSetPanditContact,
}) => {
  
  console.log(panditContactz,panditNamez,onChangeSetPanditContact,onChangeSetPanditName)  

  return (
    <Form style={{ marginTop: "8px" }}>
      <Row>
        <Col span={11}>
          <Form.Item onChange={onChangeSetPanditName}>
            <Input value={panditNamez} placeholder="Pandit Name"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col span={11}>
          <Form.Item onChange={onChangeSetPanditContact}>
            <Input value={panditContactz} placeholder="Pandit Contact"></Input>
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col span={2}>
          <Button icon={<PlusOutlined />} style={minusStyle}></Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default PanditComponent;
```

and this code to render the elements

```
data.pandit.map((p, index) => (
                <PanditComponent
                  key={index}
                  panditNamez={panditDBItems[index]["name"]}
                  panditContactz={panditDBItems[index]["contact"]}
                  onChangeSetPanditName={(e) =>
                    // setPanditDBItems([{ name: "AAAAA", contact: "1234" }])
                    setPanditDBItems([{...panditDBItems,}])
                  }
                  onChangeSetPanditContact={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
                />
              ))
            : null}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

OK I solve this

if we break this question into simple words how to update state of array of objects like

panditDBItems = [{name:"aa",contact:12},{name:"b",contact:21}]

we can use do something

```
panditDBItems.map((p, index) => (
                <PanditComponent
                  key={index}
                  panditNamez={panditDBItems[index]["name"]}
                  panditContactz={panditDBItems[index]["contact"]}
                  onChangeSetPanditName={(e) => {
                    let newPanditDBItems = [...panditDBItems];
                    newPanditDBItems[index]["name"] = e.target.value;
                    setPanditDBItems(newPanditDBItems);
                  }}
                  onChangeSetPanditContact={(e) => {
                    let newPanditDBItems = [...panditDBItems];
                    newPanditDBItems[index]["contact"] = e.target.value;
                    setPanditDBItems(newPanditDBItems);
                  }}
                />
              )
```